# Differences between phenols and alcohols

Tags: organic-chemistry, alcohols, phenols

I know ***phenols are more acidic as compared to alcohols***, but are they considered different from alcohols?

Sure, you can study something as a subset, but are **phenols** considered a subset of alcohols, or are they considered as completely different from alcohols? My confusion is due to the fact that both of them contain a hydroxyl group.

[image: Phenol]
[image: Alcohol]

Comment: Then what are the difference between above mentioned ones and carboxylic acid?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Nope. Alcohols consist of an -$\ce{OH}$ group bonded to a *saturated* carbon ($\mathrm{sp^3}$ hybridized, no multiple bonds).

[IUPAC says:](https://goldbook.iupac.org/A00204.html)

> ## alcohols
>
> Compounds in which a hydroxy group, -$\ce{OH}$, is attached to a saturated carbon atom $\ce{R3COH}$. The term 'hydroxyl' refers to the radical species, $\ce{HO^.}$.

[and](https://goldbook.iupac.org/P04539.html)

> ## phenols
>
> Compounds having one or more hydroxy groups attached to a benzene or other arene ring, *e.g.*, 2-naphthol:
>
> [image: 2-naphthol structure]
> <sub>(source: [iupac.org](https://goldbook.iupac.org/SVG/P04539.png))</sub>

A phenol consists of an -$\ce{OH}$ bonded to an unsaturated $\mathrm{sp^2}$ carbon. Thus, it does not qualify as an alcohol. One *can* classify it as an [enol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enol), though.

---

Really, to me, the classification doesn't matter. Classifications are artificial, what is important is, how well the properties fit in the classification.

Many of the alcohol properties depend upon:

- Its unsaturated nature: oxidation to ketone/aldehyde/acid
- The weaker $\ce{R-O}$ bond and its ability to easily break and form an $\ce{R+}$ cation (this makes it a good participant in $\mathrm{S_N1}$ reactions)

Phenol can obviously not be oxidised at the $\ce{OH}$ to a ketone/acid (though one *can* do stuff to make it into a quinone). Phenylic carbocations are unstable, thus we don't get any $\mathrm{S_N1}$ reactions, and the $\ce{Ph-O}$ bond stays put.

On the other hand, most of the reactions of phenol depend upon its

- Aromatic phenyl ring: All the EAS reactions
- Weaker $\ce{O-H}$ bond (*i.e.*, acidic nature): Reimer-Tiemann reaction, etc.

Thus phenols and alcohols don't have too many reactions in common. So, in this case, they have been classified in a sensible manner--if phenols were classified as alcohols, we would basically be clubbing two radically different classes of compounds under one umbrella.

Comment: Actually the question in my book was "Which of these cannot be considered as an alcohol", and phenol was an option.

Comment: @kartik It is not an alcohol by definition. The second part of my answer deals with why we cannot even _consider_ it as one.

Comment: @KartikAnand, one must remember that what is taught in a course is not always necessarily agreed on in the field. The "Central Dogma" comes to mind.

Comment: (Re:last paragraph) I agree that classifications are somewhat artificial. But I disagree that phenols and alcohols have nearly no reactions in common. Both alcohols and phenols are capable of acting as weakly acidic species; when deprotonated, their conjugate bases are both strong bases and good nucleophiles; and they can undergo many reactions in common at oxygen, such as alkylation, silylation, acylation, and many others. This is a significant facet of the chemistry of alcohols and should not be overlooked.

Comment: @james_ash: (I converted your post to a comment, once you have 50 rep you can comment yourself). Hmm, I _sort of_ disagree with your comments on their strengths as acids/bases/nucleophiles, but that is only because their _relative_ strengths are quite different. I'll edit my post, though--you're absolutely right about the other reactions. Basically I want to say that their nature is different enough for them to be classified differently.